# Fast query for closest point between line and AABB in 3D

Tags: collision-detection

How can I efficiently find the closest points between an infinite line and an AABB in 3D space?

I have a naive solution that involves finding the closest points to all 12 edges of the AABB to the line and picking the closest pair, which works, but is not very performant. I need something faster for my use case.

In my search, I've found plenty of literature on finding collisions between lines and AABBs, and several implementations of the naive algorithm. But is there anything better?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18436/most-efficient-aabb-vs-ray-collision-algorithms

Comment: @markasoftware nice but the solutions in the link just give the distance. it looks like this question is asking for a pair of points (i.e., their coordinates) -- one on the line and one on the box -- that satisfies the minimum distance. since there can be many such pairs (i.e., non-uniqueness of solution in the general case, although usually not in the typical case) in edge situations, presumably any one such pair of points would suffice (?). this might be a natural extension to the solutions in the link but i'm not so sure.

Comment: @markasoftware Those are for collision detection, not nearest points.

Answer (score 1):

My (also fairly naïve) solution would be to choose the point on the line closest to the centre of the AABB and work outward from that point following the example from here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133217/minimal-distance-to-a-cube-in-2d-and-3d-from-a-point-lying-outside

Then iterate along the line until the distance was no longer decreasing (has to sweep outwards in each direction.)

This would have the benefit of being very fast in the cases where the line is parallel to a face or an edge but I don't know if it would be faster than your naïve solution on lines that have no parallel aspects to the AABB.

(Of course the solution from the maths stack exchange would take a bit of adapting from pseudo-code to the language of your choice and you would have to calculate the co-ordinates of the vector to get your points after you had found the shortest path.)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, are you suggesting to calculate distance between the 12 edges and a point on line while varying the point? Also, how to find the closest point on the edge?

Answer (score 1):

First thing off my mind, you don't need to check for all 12 edges. For e.g. let's say you want to find the closest point to line A. With some simple math, you can find a perpendicular line A' passing through the center of AABB. You can find the intersection of A and A', let's call that point P. So point P is basically the projection of the center of the AABB on line A, there's mathematical formulae to calculate that. I'll add it if you could tell us how your infinite line is defined (Is it defined by two points, or is it defined by a point and a direction vector?).
Now you can look at the coordinates of P to check which octant it lies in with respect to the center of the AABB, i.e. subtract the coordinates of the center from coordinates of P, this will result in a basic translation of the center to orgin (origin shift). The closest vertex of the cube will be the one in the same octant.

Now, the closest edge to the line will be one of the 3 edges that this vertex belongs to.

This will work in 1/4th the time of your algo.

Comment: This sounds very promising but perhaps you could clarify how you get from P (the projection of the AABB's center onto the line) to P', which appears to be a point on a face of the AABB which is why you refer to quadrants -- a planar concept.

Comment: @Salmonstrikes Beg your pardon, there is no point P'. When I wrote P' I considered P as the center of AABB. Rereading this, I realise I never named the center, instead P is the projection of the center of AABB. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Got it. One last thing: did you mean octants instead of quadrants, with the convention that the AABB is centered at the origin?

Comment: @Salmonstrikes Yep got me again. Thank you for the corrections!

Comment: Easy enough to guess what you meant; it was more about performance than terminology, honestly -- four sets of inequality checks vs eight. It would be great if the two approaches (this and the one in the question) could be fleshed out for comparison somehow...

Comment: I think OP is using something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993953/closest-points-between-two-lines) for each of the 12 edges, which could be reduced to just 3 edges with this approach. The overhead of this approach would be calculating A' and intersection of A and A'. Finding some perpendicular line to A is a small part of the solution to finding closest points (as you can see in the link above), that's being reduced to just once instead of 8 times as in OP's approach. So I suppose this will be a faster implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your line will be something like cv + p, where v is the direction vector and p a point it passes through.

The direction to the closest point on your box from the line will be perpendicular to the line, so get a pair of normals to `v`, say `n` and `m`.

The actual closest point will be a linear combination of `n` and `m` with a point on the line.  (You start from a point on the line, and follow some perpendicular to the line off to your destination point, every perpendicular to the line is a linear combination of the normals through that point.)

So solve `an + bm + cv + p = s`, where `s` is each corner of your box.

Without loss of generality, we can assume `v` does not have zero in either of its first two components.  (If it has one, permute the indices to make it the third.  If it has two, this becomes a much simpler problem, which we can solve separately.)

That means we can take `n = (1, 0, N)` and `m = (0, 1, M)`.

Since `n * v = 0` and `m * v = 0`, we can find `N = -v1/v3` and `M = -v2/v3`.  We are not going to do all this substitution, it is enough to just know those are numbers, not variables.

Now we want to solve `an + bm + cv = s - p`.  Which we can do with normal algebra.  We get

```
c = (s3 - p3 - N(s1 - p1)- M(s2 - p2))/(v3 - N v1 - M v2)
```

and `cv + p` is then the nearest point on your line to that corner.

Meanwhile we also have:

```
b = s2 - p2 - v2 c
a = s1 - p1 - v1 c
```

And the distance of the line from your corner is `|an + bm|` so the distance squared is

```
D^2 = (an + bm) * (an + bm) = (a^2 + b^2 + (aM + bM)^2)
```

As you look at corners, you can consider the fact you have a box.  Choose a corner and go to an neighbor, then to the neighbor that puts you diagonally from that corner.  If one of those three values is farther away than both of the other two in the same direction, the nearest point will not be on edges going to it.  That removes all the edges involving it.  Since the line might go right through your box, it is possible for this not to happen.  But it is highly unlikely.

For each pair of corners (that are not ruled out) that constitute an edge, we have a range of `c` values `x c0 + (1-x) c1` for `x in [0,1]` which represent a range of closest points on the line to the closest points on the edge.

The corresponding `a` and `b`  values are

```
a = s1-p1-v2(x c0 + (1-x)c1) = s1-p1-v2-(c0-c1)v2 x
b = s2-p2-v1(x c0 + (1-x)c1) = s2-p2-v1-(c0-c1)v1 x
```

Again, it only matters that the constants are known, so let's just write these as:

```
a = A0 + A1x
b = B0 + B1x
```

Now, from above

```
D^2 = (a^2 + b^2 + (aN + bM)^2)
```

so we can get the squared distance in terms of x.

```
D^2 = (A0 + A1 x)^2 + (B0 + B1 x)^2 + 
      (A0 N + A1 Nx)^2 + (B0 M + B1 MX)^2
```

Multiplying this all out, the x term is going to be the middle term of each square and the x^2 term is going to be the square term of each square.

And clearly the minimum for a parabola `k + rx + qx^2` is where `r + 2qx = 0` at 'x = -1/2 r/q, by differentiation.

So the minimum will be for

```
x = -(A0 A1 + B0 B2 + (NA0 A1 + MB0 B1))/
     (A1^2 + B1^2 + (A1 N + B1 M)^2)
```

When `x` is between zero and 1, you have a minimum or maximum.  By comparing the outcomes between these, you should be able to discard the maximums.

If the minimum would be on a face, not an edge, you will have too many qualifying values.  In that case clearly the answer is zero -- the line hits the box.

Comment: Good attempt! Quick clarification request: you mention "For each pair of corners that constitute an edge...<further calculations involving `x`>". If this means that you're running the minimization routine 12 times, it might not meet the asker's requirement of being faster than their 12-edge check. It would be great if you could clarify what your answer implies in terms of performance.

Comment: But 'running the minimization routine' is evaluating very straightforward arithmetic which is given.

Comment: @Salmonstrikes I have also added the observation that you don't necessarily have to look at all the edges.  Corners that constitute a face give you enough information to discard the farther of them from consideration.   You would only end up looking at all the corners if the line goes through the box.  But then you would get three candidates right away.  So the odds are that you only ever look at four points and the edges that touch them.  So I guess i have included all the algebra and omitted strategic considerations that leave this short of an algorithm.  I will return to it later.